# Problema con mi Visual Studio - No reconoce Proyectos

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dotnetcore

Buenas.
Estoy intentando abrir la solución de mi proyecto en Visual Studio 2022,pero cuando abro la solución de mi proyecto no me aparecen los proyectos que tengo en la solución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando voy a el explorador de archivos de mi solución aparecen todas las carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado reiniciando el ordenador y reiniciando el IDE, pero no consigo solventarlo.

Comment: ahi no esta el archivo de solucion.. y tambien, fijate si no hay algun error en los logs...

Comment: Sí pero justo esta en la carpeta raiz y no veo logs...

Comment: me pasa creando cualquier solución/proyecto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haz intentado hacer clic derecho en la solución y agrega>proyecto existente?
Otra alternativa puede ser abrir el proyecto MVC que tienes dan clic en el archivo csproj.

El error pudo ocurrir porque creaste el proyecto pero sin estar en esa solución.

Comment: lo de agregar proyecto existente si y no funciona. Lo otro del .csproj te refieres a darle click y que se abra desde ahi?

Comment: así es, intenta de esa manera.

Comment: vale ya te aviso cuando lo haga esta noche

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo la respuesta anterior, importé el proyecto existente (el archivo csproj) en la solución, pero antes de poder hacerlo tuve que cambiar la versión de mi SDK a una versión mas antigua, y para ello instalé una versión más antigua de mi SDK y hice un archivo JSON con un nombre 'global' y con extensión .JSON donde configure una versión más antigua del SDK de mi proyecto:

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "6.0.417"
    }
  }
```

Este archivo debe estar a la altura de la raíz del proyecto, y aunque en este archivo pongas una versión más antigua, a la hora de crear el proyecto puedes usar una versión mas actual.

Para poder ver las versiones de SDK instaladas en tu ordenador puedes abrir la consola CMD y poner el siguiente comando:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

Esto desplegará las versiones de SDK instaladas en tu ordenador.

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además deberás editar el archivo .csproj con un editor de texto, cambiando las configuraciones a la versión actual de tu SDK.